# How to remove 'Buy it Now ' button on shopify when inventory is less than 5 (integrated with Rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to remove 'Buy it now' button and replace it with another button when inventory of a product is less than 5. Please help me out with this.

Comment: You need to check the product code and make changes to code where the `{{form | payment_button}}` are added, and make sure this code runs when inventory satisfy your conditions.

Comment: ok thanks, will try this.